# Connection to Exchange mail server refused using IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I have a bit of jave code which is successful in connecting to a mail server using IMAP. However when trying to connect to the MS Exchange server at client site I am receiving "connection refused. 
Is it possible that the exchange server is able to refuse connections not being made via the Outlook client?

Comment: Im sure it has to do with the fact that Outlook is an actual server itself, and with it being ran by Windows, it has its own way of connecting. IMAP is much simpler, as any person can use it as on MAC, but unlike Mac, Windows does not allow as much freedom when connecting to the more internal stuff

Answer (score 0):

More likely the Exchange server doesn't have IMAP support enabled, which is why the machine (not the server) is refusing the connection.